# How can I debug,when use openssl_verify() return false?

Tags: java, php, openssl, rsa

I use PHP to verify the sign string,which is post from JAVA, the code like :

```
$result = (bool)openssl_verify($sign_data, $sign, $public_key);
openssl_free_key($public_key);
while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
        echo $msg . "<br />\n";
var_dump($result);die;
```

Then I got a `false`,and I googled a whole day,but had no answer.Can you get me some advice.

PS: the var `$public_key` is a public key of RSA, I checked it, is `resource(1183) of type (OpenSSL key)`.

Comment: [`openssl_error_string`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php) seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you, and I try the `openssl_error_string`,it say:`error:04091077:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:wrong signature length`

Comment: So you know that the sign_data and sign for this public key do not match.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must keep the public_peky.pem to be right.Then about var `$sign_data`, think aout to do `urldecode()` once or even twice.About var `$sign`, it always need to do `base64_decode()`.